# JMF on 64bit java?

Tags: java, video, 64-bit, webcam, jmf

I know JMF is pretty much dead and whatnot, but I do know that it can still be used.
I intend to use it for personal uses and don't expect that much from it.

I have managed to install the 32bit JMF and when I run JMStudio it somehow magically works even though all of my java jres and sdks are 64-bit.

I personally believe that this proves that it CAN work.
When creating a program importing the jmf.jar as a library, my code compiles perfectly.
Only at runtime do i get any form of error with the common:

> Exception in thread "VFW Request Thread"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JMFSecurityManager:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib\jmvfw.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD
>   64-bit platform

Obviously there is a problem with using a 32bit dll on a 64bit system.

My question is if its not compatible:

1. how does JMStudio work perfectly fine (it definitely uses java)
2. how can I fix it so that my program can run without depending on this dll
3. or other workarounds

Thanks a ton to anyone who has ever tried this before.
Java is definitely lacking in native specific tools such as webcams.

Comment: I'm guessing but could you have installed the cross-platform version of JMF to get JMStudio working?  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/setup-138642.html  That version apparently doesn't rely on native code ... though this comes at a cost of not providing sound.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is the 64bit Java JRE/JDK trying to use the 32bit JMF, and/or JMF having a problem with the path that Windows 7 chooses as a default to install it to.

I have had success following the instructions posted here:
[Oracle Forums: Install JMF on Windows 7 64bit](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9902917&#9902917)

It basically boils down to:

1. Install a 32bit JRE/JDK, and ensure that this is what your code uses.
2. Install JMF to simple directory in the root of C: (i.e. c:\JMF2.1.1e)

Good luck!

Comment: The oracle link has changed: [Oracle Forums:Install JMF on Windows 7](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11146908#11146908).

Answer (score 0):

JMFStudio is 32 bit supporting software so we must install 32bit support JDK and also Eclipse then we not get any exceptions as you mentioned in above and errors.

For my case it works fine.
and also

Try to remove unused jdk path in environment variable, if duplicate path present then also it not works fine 
other wise you should re-install OS.